# How to normalize dataset with mixed data (continuous and count)?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, count-data, standardization, mixed-type-data

I am trying to determine what procedure should I use to feature engineer the most descriptive possible dataset to predict a binary outcome. The dataset has variables that are count-valued with different max values, and continuous variables.

I know I can standardize or normalize the continuous variables, and the ones in my dataset do follow a good approximation of a Gaussian distribution, but this makes these continuous values way smaller than those that appear in count variables $(\geq 10 for all count-valued covariates)$.

Similarly, I don't know if it is advisable to adjust count data (which in this case seems to follow Poisson distributions) via normalization or standardization.

I have read that these problems are algorithm-specific, do these transformations affect Neural Network approaches?